# ASP.net datatable is returning no values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

i hope you can help with my issue. I'm trying to fill out a form from my database using a datatable. All seems to work fine but i get no data returned. Can anyone explain why? I've looked at the debug and there seems to be no errors and nothing looks like its failed. Here's my code behind (vb.net)

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Net.Mail

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub getData(ByVal user As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(constr)
    connection.Open()
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblContent WHERE CID = @ID", connection)
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString("ID"))
    sqlDa.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ID.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CID").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Heading").ToString
        TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("ContText").ToString
        Label2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Location").ToString
    End If
    connection.Close()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        getData(Me.User.Identity.Name)
    End If
End Sub
```

Presentation layer:

```
<h2><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h2>
<asp:TextBox ID="ID" runat="server" Visible="false">    </asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Heading" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>  
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="SingleLine" Text="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Content" CssClass="label"></asp:Label><br />     
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I'm passing through the ID from another page via the query string (ID=5 as an example). There is data in my database and all labels/textboxes have the right IDs etc. I just can see what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: _"all labels/textboxes have the right IDs etc"_ so what is wrong? Have you used the debugger? As an aside, you should use the `Using`-statement for your connection and dataadapter. It ensures that the connection gets closed, even on error. Also, methods should begin with an upper case letter and if they don't return anything they should not nstart with `Get`.

Comment: Hi Tim - There is not data returned to populate the text boxes/lables. I tried the debugger but there were no errors. Do you have an example of the using statement you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: Can you put profiler to SQL server to check whether it is reaching there or not?

Comment: For new SqlCommand put Commandtype.Text

Comment: Hi Amit. how do you mean profiler? I'm not sure if i've used that before? I've used the same connection string on a different page and that's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try to pass the correct type instead of string:

```
Using sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
    Dim idParam = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    Dim id As Int32
    If Not Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString("ID"), id) Then Throw New Exception("Not a valid ID-parameter!")
    idParam.Value = id
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(idParam)
    sqlDa.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

By the way, also use the `Using`-statement for the connection. As an aside, you don't need to open/close the connection with `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(table)` since that is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the time and reply to look at this Tim. Unfortunately it seems that it's still not pulling through any data. I've debugged it in visual studio and in chrome but both are showing no errors, just a blank form with no data. What i found odd is that i tried an ID as 'abc' (?ID=abc) and no error was shown? Which i guess it should have somewhere as it's not an int type. Am i debugging this wrong or is visual studio telling me lies? Thanks

Comment: @BenWilliams: it doesn't sound as if you've really used the debugger. Set a breakpoint in this method and seee what happens on every line. If the query string id is "abc" you'd clearly get the exception which i throw above. So either this method is not executed or you don't notice that the exception happened.